# Primeng p-columnFilter get column name based on filtered table column

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable, primeng-table

I want to get filtered column names from primeng table. How to add event on p-columnfilter to display the filtered column names?

```
<th style="min-width:15rem">
            <div class="flex align-items-center">
                Name
                <p-columnFilter type="text" field="name" display="menu"></p-columnFilter>
            </div>
        </th>
        <th style="min-width:15rem">
            <div class="flex align-items-center">
                Country
                <p-columnFilter type="text" field="country.name" display="menu"></p-columnFilter>
            </div>
        </th>
```